# iPhone: Draw rotated text?

Tags: iphone, text, drawing, rotation

I want to draw some text in a view, rotated 90°. I'm pretty new to iPhone development, and poking around the web reveals a number of different solutions. I've tried a few and usually end up with my text getting clipped.

What's going on here? I *am* drawing in a fairly small space (a table view cell), but there has to be a "right" way to do this… right?

---

**Edit:** Here are a couple of examples. I'm trying to display the text "**12345**" along the black bar at the left.

1. First attempt, from [RJShearman on the Apple Discussions](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=7878554#7878554)

   ```
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextSelectFont (context, "Helvetica-Bold", 16.0, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
   CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (context, kCGTextFill);
   CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   CGContextSetTextMatrix (context, CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.f, -1.f ), M_PI/2));
   CGContextShowTextAtPoint (context, 21.0, 55.0, [_cell.number cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], [_cell.number length]);
   CGContextRestoreGState(context);
   ```

   [image: Attempt one. The one and part of the two are clipped out.]
   <sub>(source: [deeptechinc.com](http://dev.deeptechinc.com/sidney/share/iphonerotation/attempt1.png))</sub>
2. Second attempt, from [zgombosi on iPhone Dev SDK](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/10315-rotate-text-problem.html#post97064). Identical results (the font was slightly smaller here, so there's less clipping).

   ```
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGPoint point = CGPointMake(6.0, 50.0);
   CGContextSaveGState(context);
   CGContextTranslateCTM(context, point.x, point.y);
   CGAffineTransform textTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1.57);
   CGContextConcatCTM(context, textTransform);
   CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);
   [[UIColor redColor] set];
   [_cell.number drawAtPoint:point withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]];
   CGContextRestoreGState(context);
   ```

   [Attempt two. There is almost identical clipping http://dev.deeptechinc.com/sidney/share/iphonerotation/attempt2.png](http://dev.deeptechinc.com/sidney/share/iphonerotation/attempt2.png)

Comment: There are indeed a few ways to go about this. Providing some detail about what exactly you've tried and how exactly it didn't work out (how/where did it get clipped?) would make it easier to answer usefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the my table cell was *always* initialized 44px high regardless of the row height, so all of my drawing was getting clipped 44px from the top of the cell.

To draw larger cells it was necessary to set the content view's `autoresizingMask` with

```
cellContentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

or

```
cellContentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

…and `drawRect` is called with the correct size. In a way, this makes sense, because `UITableViewCell`'s `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` makes no mention of the size of the cell, and only the table view actually knows how big each row is going to be, based on its own size and its delegate's response to `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I read the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/index.html) until the drawing model and functions started to make sense, and the code to draw my rotated text became simple and obvious:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextRotateCTM(context, -(M_PI/2));
[_cell.number drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-57.0, 5.5) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0]];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Thanks for the tips, it looks like I'm all set.

Answer (score 3):

Use :-

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- 90.0f * M_PI / 180.0f);
```

where label is the object of UILabel.

Comment: Thanks, @Sorted! Actually, I wasn’t using a `UILabel` — I was drawing in a custom table view cell.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tip.  I presume you're doing this drawing in drawRect.  Why don't you draw a frame around drawRect to see how big the rect is and if that is why you get clipping.

An alternative is to put your text in a UILabel, and then rotate that 90 degrees when you make your cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: mahboudz's suggestion will probably be your path of least resistance. You can rotate the UILabel 90deg with this: [label setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(-90.0f))]; You'll just have to calculate your cell height based upon the label width.  -Matt

Answer (score 1):

You know about the UITableViewDelegate method [heightForRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) right?

Here's a [simple tutorial on various graphics level methods.](http://trailsinthesand.com/exploring-iphone-graphics-part-1/)  Presuming you know how big your text is you should be able to size your table view row size appropriately.

Also, I'd check to make sure that the bounds after any transform actually meet your expectations.  (Either use a debugger or log statement to verify this).

Comment: I do know about `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, the row itself is fine. The text is getting clipped during the transform and ends up cut off in the middle of the cell.

Comment: Could you show us the specific code you use to do the transform?

Answer (score 1):

to what @Sidnicious said, and what i collected through out stack overflow, i want to give a usage example - appended my code to completely draw a ruler to the left screen side, with numbers rotated:

[image: ruler screenshot]

```
RulerView : UIView


  // simple testing for iPhones (check for device descriptions to get all iPhones + iPads)
  - (float)getPPI
  {
      switch ((int)[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height) {
          case 568: // iPhone 5*
          case 667: // iPhone 6
              return 163.0;
              break;

          case 736: // iPhone 6+
              return 154.0;
              break;

          default:
              return -1.0;
              break;
      }
  }

  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
  {
      [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];


      float ppi = [self getPPI];

      if (ppi == -1.0)  // unable to draw, maybe an ipad.
          return;

      float linesDist = ppi/25.4; // ppi/mm per inch (regular size iPad would be 132.0, iPhone6+ 154.0)

      float linesWidthShort = 15.0;
      float linesWidthMid = 20.0;
      float linesWidthLong = 25.0;

      for (float i = 0, c = 0; i <= self.bounds.size.height; i = i + linesDist, c = c +1.0)
      {
          bool isMid = (int)c % 5 == 0;
          bool isLong = (int)c % 10 == 0;

          float linesWidth = isLong ? linesWidthLong : isMid ? linesWidthMid : linesWidthShort;
          UIRectFillUsingBlendMode( (CGRect){0, i, linesWidth, .5} , kCGBlendModeNormal);



          /*  FONT: Numbers without rotation (yes, is short)
          if (isLong && i > 0 && (int)c % 10 == 0)
              [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)(c/10)] drawAtPoint:(CGPoint){linesWidthLong +2, i -5} withAttributes:@{
                                                                                                                              NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9],
                                                                                                                              NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]
                                                                                                                              }];
          */


          // FONT: Numbers with rotation (yes, requires more effort)
          if (isLong && i > 0 && (int)c % 10 == 0)
          {
              NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)(c/10)];
              NSDictionary *attrs = @{
                                      NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9],
                                      NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]
                                      };
              CGSize textSize = [str sizeWithAttributes:attrs];


              CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
              CGContextSaveGState(context);

              CGContextRotateCTM(context, +(M_PI/2));
              [str drawAtPoint:(CGPoint){i - (textSize.width/2), -(linesWidthLong + textSize.height +2)} withAttributes:attrs];

              CGContextRestoreGState(context);
          }

      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After I discovered that I needed to add the following to the top of my file I liked Matt's approach. Very simple.

```
#define degreesToRadian(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)
```

mahboudz's suggestion will probably be your path of least resistance. You can rotate the UILabel 90deg with this: [label setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(-90.0f))]; You'll just have to calculate your cell height based upon the label width. -Matt – Matt Long Nov 10 at 0:09